# \hyperlink in \section (\tableofcontents)

Tags: table-of-contents, hyperlink, hypertarget

I'm currently trying to create a table of contents (`\tableofcontents`).

The headings (section name) on the individual page headers should then lead to the table of contents as `\hyperlink`.

Unfortunately I always get error messages.

Does anyone have an idea/solution?

Thanks

Code:

```
\tableofcontents
\newpage
\section{\hyperlink{tableofcontents}{Gebäude}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX!

Comment: Thanks to you and your answer!